# How to obtain a local timezone Date from a date string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone-offset

I am building an online store, most of my customers (basically all) are located in a given timezone, but my infrastructure is located in other timezone (we can assume it's UTC). I have the option for my clients to select a date for their orders, the problem is that my date component represents dates like this "YYYY-MM-DD". In am using the Date constructor like this:

```js
let dateString = "2019-06-03"
let date = new Date(dateString)
console.log(date) //This will print the local time zone representation of my dateString
console.log(date.toISOString()) //This will print the utc equivalent of my dateString
```

The problem with this is that I want the UTC representation to be calculated from the local timezone, not the other way around. Let's suppose in am located in GMT-5, when I say `let date = new Date("2019-06-06")` I want to see "2019-06-03T00:00:00.000 GMT-5" , and the ISOString should be "2019-06-03T05:00:00.000Z". How can I do this ?

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to ISO? If you want to know the exact time, just convert it to UTC on the front end and send it to the backend. If you need to display that date again on the frontend you can just pop the timestamp in a Date class and the browser will convert it to whatever timezone the user is in.

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a format. ISO 8601 specifies various formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by appending the string `T00:00:00` to the dateString before passing it to the Date() constructor.

But a word of caution, manipulating the timezone/offsets manually like this might result in incorrect data being presented.

If you are storing and retrieving all the order timestamps in UTC only, it will avoid timezone related issues and you might not need to process the timestamps like this.

```js
let dateString = "2019-06-03"
let date = new Date(dateString + "T00:00:00")
console.log(date) //This will print the local time zone representation of my dateString
console.log(date.toISOString()) //This will print the utc equivalent of my dateString
```

Comment: Parsing strings with the built–in constructor is not recommended due to browser vagaries, e.g. until very recently, Safari parsed "2019-06-03T00:00:00" as UTC instead of local. It only takes one more line of code to split the values and pass them directly the Date constructor, avoiding the built–in parser entirely. Alternatively, use *toLocaleString* with timezone set to UTC.

Comment: @RobG  I agree that browser specific implementations can bring down the logic and cause inconsistencies.